# angular 2 service not calling a php file

Tags: javascript, php, json, angular, angular2-services

i'm learning angular 2 and i make a test to connect to a database, but i get an error that: SyntaxError: unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.

so i have my xampp working on port 80 or 443.
the url of my test ( i'm using angular cli ) is: localhost:4200

this is my attempt. i have a service with this method:

```
  getUsers(){
return this._http.get('getusers.php')
  .map(res => res.json());
 }
```

the getusers.php file is located at the public folder.
this is it's content. very basic just to get some results and send them back as json:

```
 // set up the connection variables
    $db_name  = 'mydb';
    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $username = 'myusername';
    $password = 'mypass';

    // connect to the database
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);


    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';


    $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );


    $stmt->execute();


    $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );


    $json = json_encode( $result );

    echo $json;
```

so i add that in the component i import the service, initialize it in the constructor and subscribe:

```
  constructor(private _usersService: UsersService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
     this._usersService.getUsers()
       .subscribe(
         data => this.getUsers = JSON.stringify(data),
         error => alert(error),
         () => console.log("Finihed")
      );
  }
```

what am i missing here. i do tons of ajax call but first time with angular. maybe it's the ports? or something else i am missing?

best regards

Comment: That _"SyntaxError: unexpected token < in JSON"_ could mean that your php is with error. Make sure you have a completely working php code before anything. (you can use chrome's POSTMAN extension for some fancy requests)

Comment: Since you aren't sending anything, access `getusers.php` from the browser. What do you see?

Comment: i know. the first thing i did was to check the file initself, i do a var_dump and do get the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so since the situation is a cross domain with the two ports. in your call use the full url with the port:
http://localhost:80/yourproject/public/getContacts.php

and in your server side add CORS headers BEFORE outputting:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($result);
```

since i'm just testing i use the *, but this is not recommended. usuall allow a specific url.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the the ajax call to work ; 
Who ever is calling the   getUsers method should subscribe to it :

```
 getUsers(){
     return this._http.get('getusers.php')
     .map(res => res.json());
 }
```

Let's say you're calling get method here :

```
 myOtherFunction(){
     this.getUsers.subscribe((response)=>{
           console.log('response',response);

     })

}
```

Comment: hey, sorry i forgot to add this. in my component i import the service and then this: 
`  ngOnInit() {
    this._usersService.getUsers()
      .subscribe(
        data => this.getUsers = JSON.stringify(data),
        error => alert(error),
        () => console.log("Finihed")
      );
  }`